# Keras Binary Classification val_acc won't go past ~67; Full data and code included

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, dataset, data-cleaning

I'm working on a binary classification in Keras with a Tensorflow backend. No matter how much I tweak, I can't seem to get my model past a val_acc of 67%. Is there something I'm missing, or is this just simply as accurate as I can get with my data?

[Link to the data I am using](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VX-WsSfuHHxJxbWHR147bfArblUqY64-f4dJVZtgCr0/edit?usp=sharing)

**My Code**

Load and Balance dataset to a 1:1, and create validation data.

```
from sklearn.utils import resample

raw_data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

df_majority = raw_data[raw_data['RESULT']==0].iloc[1:-2,0:3].dropna()
df_minority = raw_data[raw_data['RESULT']==1].iloc[1:-2,0:3].dropna()

print(raw_data['RESULT'].value_counts())


df_majority_downsampled = resample(df_majority, 
                          replace=False,
                 n_samples=raw_data['RESULT'].value_counts()[1],
                             random_state=123)

# Combine minority class with downsampled majority class
df_downsampled = pd.concat([df_majority_downsampled,df_minority])

# Display new class counts
print(df_downsampled['RESULT'].value_counts())
print(numpy.unique(df_downsampled['RESULT']))

X = df_downsampled.iloc[1:-2,0:2].dropna()
Y = df_downsampled.iloc[1:-2,2:3].dropna()

X, XTest, Y, YTest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

print(YTest['RESULT'].value_counts()) #Just a double check to make
```

Create Model

```
def create_model(activation):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(128,activation=activation,input_dim=2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Dense(64,activation=activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(32,activation=activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(16,activation=activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(8,activation=activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(4,activation=activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(2,activation=activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
    # load weights
    model.load_weights("weights.best.hdf5")
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),metrics=['accuracy'])  

return model
model = create_model('relu')

filepath       ="weights.best.hdf5"
checkpoint     = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,monitor='val_acc',verbose=1,save_best_only=True,mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = model.fit(X,Y,epochs=2000,batch_size=32, shuffle = True,validation_data = (XTest,YTest), verbose = 0, 
     callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Predict and get score

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

predict = model.predict_classes(X)
print(numpy.unique(predict))

#for index,val in enumerate(predict):
#print("Predicted: %s, actual: %s, for val %s"(val[0],Y.iloc[index].values,X.iloc[index].values))

predict = [val[0] for val in predict]
print("ras score: ",roc_auc_score(Y,predict))


predict = model.predict(numpy.array([0.0235,0.5]).reshape(-1,2))
print(predict[0][0])
```

**Result using current model**

[image: result]

**Sok suggestion of placing Dropout before Dense: val_acc =0.65990**

[image]

Comment: one of my recommendation for you is to try to put dropout layer before dense layers, try this and tell me if this helps you?

Comment: Hey @Sok I just updated the summary with the results of placing dropout before dense. I wasn't able to see much of a change

Comment: could try playing with dropout rate? did you try removing batch norm layer because this layer is more reasonable for convolution layers? finally, why not try to use CNN, I think it's better than traditional NN.

Comment: You're trying to predict a binary output using just 2 features. Is it possible this is the best possible classifier you can get for your data? Have you benchmarked with non neural net techniques? Without knowing the context, it's hard to give more insight on it, but that seems likely.